# Data manipulation for pairwise.t.test in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

So I'm trying to do a pairwise table and retain a p-value of each pair.
Please be noted that I'm still a beginner to R.
My data looks like this (though much bigger):

```
a <- factor(c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4","ID5"))
b <- runif(5)
b1 <- runif(5)
b2 <- runif(5)
b3 <- runif(5)
c1 <- runif(5)
c2 <- runif(5)
c3 <- runif(5)
df <- data.frame(a,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3)
```

Where b1,b2,b3 should be compared to c1,c2,c3 for each row (for each ID in column a).
The end result should be something like:

```
a <- cbind(a,Adjusted_P_Values)
```

Where the head(a,1) would look like:

```
head(a,1)
    a        b1        b2        b3        c1        c2
1 ID1 0.1337694 0.7347543 0.5808391 0.4324976 0.5378458
         c3        Adjusted_P_value
1 0.6368778        0.99
```

where each row has its corresponding P-value.
A function I have found which I think could do the trick is `pairwise.t.test`.
(Currently, I'm just running a loop for each row and doing a normal t-test and then correct them with p.adjust, but I can't do pooled sd---which I would like.)

So my issue now is how I construct the data so that R likes it. I can use `melt.data.frame`from reshape2 library, but it wont give me the correct structure.
I use it like this:

```
Test_Data <- melt(df, "a", c("b1","b2","b3","c1","c2","c3"))
```

But I loose the row symmetry.
As, when I now do `pairwise.t.test` I have to use either the "a" column or the "variable" column created by melt, hence I either get a comparison between the replicates or between the IDs.
So, simply my question is:
how do I structure the data so that each row is tested and I get a p-value for each row, and where each treatment (b or c) has a standard deviation based on all the rows (one sd for all b's and one for all c's)?
I have been googeling a lot looking for similar problems (and tutorials on pairwise.t.test) but without success.

Comment: Try `lapply(split(Test_Data, Test_Data$a), function(TD) t.test(value ~ grepl("b", variable), TD))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution using the [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) package.

First, adjust the format of the data frame to the following structure.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  gather(Column, Value, -a) %>%
  extract(Column, into = c("Group", "Number"), regex = "([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)")
df2
#      a Group Number       Value
# 1  ID1     b      1 0.640310605
# 2  ID2     b      1 0.009495756
# 3  ID3     b      1 0.232550506
# 4  ID4     b      1 0.666083758
# 5  ID5     b      1 0.514251141
# 6  ID1     b      2 0.693591292
# 7  ID2     b      2 0.544974836
# 8  ID3     b      2 0.282733584
# 9  ID4     b      2 0.923433484
# 10 ID5     b      2 0.292315840
# 11 ID1     b      3 0.837295628
# 12 ID2     b      3 0.286223285
# 13 ID3     b      3 0.266820780
# 14 ID4     b      3 0.186722790
# 15 ID5     b      3 0.232225911
# 16 ID1     c      1 0.316612455
# 17 ID2     c      1 0.302693371
# 18 ID3     c      1 0.159046003
# 19 ID4     c      1 0.039995918
# 20 ID5     c      1 0.218799541
# 21 ID1     c      2 0.810598552
# 22 ID2     c      2 0.525697547
# 23 ID3     c      2 0.914658166
# 24 ID4     c      2 0.831345047
# 25 ID5     c      2 0.045770263
# 26 ID1     c      3 0.456091482
# 27 ID2     c      3 0.265186672
# 28 ID3     c      3 0.304672203
# 29 ID4     c      3 0.507306870
# 30 ID5     c      3 0.181096208
```

Second, split the data frame and conduct `pairwise.t.test`, and then extract the P values.

```
p_value <- df2 %>%
  split(.$a) %>%
  map(function(x) pairwise.t.test(x$Value, x$Group, paired = TRUE)) %>%
  map_dbl("p.value")
p_value
#       ID1       ID2       ID3       ID4       ID5 
# 0.3391364 0.5043753 0.4598274 0.6764142 0.1178471
```

Finally, added the P values to the original data frame as a new column.

```
df_final <- df %>% mutate(Adjusted_P_value = p_value)
df_final
#     a          b1        b2        b3         c1         c2        c3 Adjusted_P_value
# 1 ID1 0.640310605 0.6935913 0.8372956 0.31661245 0.81059855 0.4560915        0.3391364
# 2 ID2 0.009495756 0.5449748 0.2862233 0.30269337 0.52569755 0.2651867        0.5043753
# 3 ID3 0.232550506 0.2827336 0.2668208 0.15904600 0.91465817 0.3046722        0.4598274
# 4 ID4 0.666083758 0.9234335 0.1867228 0.03999592 0.83134505 0.5073069        0.6764142
# 5 ID5 0.514251141 0.2923158 0.2322259 0.21879954 0.04577026 0.1810962        0.1178471
```

**DATA**

```
set.seed(1234)

a <- factor(c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4","ID5"))
b <- runif(5)
b1 <- runif(5)
b2 <- runif(5)
b3 <- runif(5)
c1 <- runif(5)
c2 <- runif(5)
c3 <- runif(5)
df <- data.frame(a,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3)
```

#### Edit:

In order to correctly map the P-values back onto the data frame, the data frame has to be ordered on the 'a' column.

Comment: Ok, I think this is exactly what I want. Gonna need to read and learn a bit about the details. One thing that I don't understand is how I choose which columns to test? Because, I simplified the data set I posted a bit and need to be a bit more selective (I have more groups than b and c). I will accept this answer because I can make data frames that works with this explanation! :) Thank you very much.

Comment: The `pairwise.t.test()` function needs a `paired=TRUE` argument to conducts paired tests.

Comment: @LenGreski Thanks for your comment. I have updated my post to set `paired=TRUE`.

Comment: @www - the arguments for `pairwise.t.test()` are a bit funky because one would expect the default for this function to be `paired=TRUE`.  I was about to post my answer when I noticed your post go up on the site, and had to figure out why the p-values didn't match across our answers.

Comment: @LenGreski I think "pairwise" of `pairwise.t.test()` means "pairwise comparisons between group levels" for multiple testing, not "comparison of each pair". That is a little bit confusing. This is my first time to study this function thanks to OP's question. And thank you again.

Comment: I'll admit that I'm "old school" in that I learned to conduct pairwise t-tests many years ago by splitting the data into two columns so each observation had a "before" and "after" column, and the t-test essentially subtracts before from after and calculates a t-test on the result.

Comment: To your answer, would you mind adding that the data frame has to be sorted on the column 'a' in order to map the p-values correctly back on the data frame? Eg., if the ID would have been c("ID2", "ID3", "ID1", "ID5", "ID4") this will not accurately map the p-values back to onto the dataframe.This will help future readers as well.

Comment: @Baraliuh Good idea. I don’t have access to a computer right now and it is difficult to edit post on a phone. Could you edit my post? I will approve your edit later.

Answer (score 3):

My approach was slightly different than the other answer, spreading the data into two columns, `b` and `c` by time measure (1 - 3), and then using `t.test(...,paired=TRUE)` to conduct a pairwise t-test.

```
set.seed(1234)
a <- factor(c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4","ID5"))
b <- runif(5)
b1 <- runif(5)
b2 <- runif(5)
b3 <- runif(5)
c1 <- runif(5)
c2 <- runif(5)
c3 <- runif(5)
df <- data.frame(a,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 gather(.,key="variable",value="value",-a) %>%
     extract(.,variable,into = c("measure", "time"), 
             regex = "([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)") %>%
      spread(.,measure,value) -> spreadData
# split by ID to conduct paired t-tests by ID
dataList <- split(spreadData,spreadData$a)
pValues <- unlist(lapply(dataList,function(x){
   t.test(x$b,x$c,paired=TRUE)$p.value
}))
df$p.value <- pValues
df
```

...and the output:

```
> df
    a          b1        b2        b3         c1         c2
1 ID1 0.640310605 0.6935913 0.8372956 0.31661245 0.81059855
2 ID2 0.009495756 0.5449748 0.2862233 0.30269337 0.52569755
3 ID3 0.232550506 0.2827336 0.2668208 0.15904600 0.91465817
4 ID4 0.666083758 0.9234335 0.1867228 0.03999592 0.83134505
5 ID5 0.514251141 0.2923158 0.2322259 0.21879954 0.04577026
         c3   p.value
1 0.4560915 0.3391364
2 0.2651867 0.5043753
3 0.3046722 0.4598274
4 0.5073069 0.6764142
5 0.1810962 0.1178471
>
```

**NOTE:** if one modifies the code from the other answer to include `paired=TRUE` argument, the p-values across the two solutions match.

## Alternative approach: run t-test on difference between c and b

Given the commentary on this post about pairwise t-tests, I thought I'd illustrate what's happening with a pairwise test. Essentially for each time period 1 - 3, we subtract the `b` value from the `c` value, and run a t-test on the difference. Since we've reduced the data to a single column, there's no need for the `paired=` argument, but the test produces the same results as passing 2 columns with the `paired=TRUE` argument to `t.test()`.

```
# alternative 2: subtract b from c and use regular t-test
# to show how pairwise works
spreadData$difference <- spreadData$c - spreadData$b
dataList <- split(spreadData,spreadData$a)
pValues <- unlist(lapply(dataList,function(x){
     t.test(x$difference)$p.value
}))
df$p.value <- pValues
df
```

...and the output:

```
> spreadData$difference <- spreadData$c - spreadData$b
> dataList <- split(spreadData,spreadData$a)
> pValues <- unlist(lapply(dataList,function(x){
+      t.test(x$difference)$p.value
+ }))
> df$p.value <- pValues
> df
    a          b1        b2        b3         c1         c2
1 ID1 0.640310605 0.6935913 0.8372956 0.31661245 0.81059855
2 ID2 0.009495756 0.5449748 0.2862233 0.30269337 0.52569755
3 ID3 0.232550506 0.2827336 0.2668208 0.15904600 0.91465817
4 ID4 0.666083758 0.9234335 0.1867228 0.03999592 0.83134505
5 ID5 0.514251141 0.2923158 0.2322259 0.21879954 0.04577026
         c3   p.value
1 0.4560915 0.3391364
2 0.2651867 0.5043753
3 0.3046722 0.4598274
4 0.5073069 0.6764142
5 0.1810962 0.1178471
>
```

Comment: I bet this is also a very good answer (if I had higher reputation I would up-vote), though, I have a hard time understanding what is happening; gonna need to play around a bit with it on my fake dataset. From both answers it is clear I need to read more about this tidyr package. One question which comes to mind is how do you pick certain column names with the `regex` function?

Comment: @Baraliuh - no problem, welcome to StackOverflow. The input and output column names are specified in the `extract()` function, and the `regex=` argument specifies a regular expression to split the data in the input column into the output columns specified in the `into=` argument. More information about the Tidyverse is available at the [Tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org) website.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to Baraliuh solution:

map_dbl("p.value") does not work, however, 
map_df( "p.value") work in my case